# Transpiled webpack bundle does not export hyphenated package name via require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, fluent-ffmpeg

I am importing `fluent-ffmpeg` with: `import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'` in one file.

After running webpack, I receive this error: 
`Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: fluent is not defined`

I looked inside the transpiled file and I found `fluent-ffmpeg` included like so:
`function(e,t){e.exports=fluent-ffmpeg}`

After changing the line to read: `function(e,t){e.exports=require("fluent-ffmpeg")}` the programs work.

Is there a way to configure webpack to correctly require `fluent-ffmpeg` when transpiling?

Edit: I am using this electron react webpack boilerplate to build a desktop application - https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

**Update:**
I've created a repo to show the bug - https://github.com/the4dpatrick/congenial-barnacle. The difference between [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) and this repo can be seen in a [single commit](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/congenial-barnacle/commit/112cebf4df46e4683cc01fcb80e6df253a9924ce)

To see bug:

- `npm i`
- packaging the electron app (`npm run package`)
- opening the app which is under the release dir.
- Alert opens with error

Comment: are you closing the opening `'`? i.e. `import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'`

Comment: Yes, and even changing the line to `const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg")` results in the same.

Edit: In the question I just had a typo where I left out the trailing `'`

Comment: Webpack is a client side module bundler, even if you manage to create the bundle it won't work on a browser since `fluent-ffmpeg` uses node's `os` and `child_process` modules, am I right?

Comment: @MauricioPoppe I'm using this electron react boilerplate - https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate. It's for a desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by simply setting the `output.libraryTarget` setting `within webpack.config.electron.js` file to `commonjs2`.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
```

For further details read: [chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate#232](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/232)

Comment: where the file `webpack.config.electron.js` should be placed ? 
is it possible to set this in  `webpack.config.base.js` ?